# How to select only the highest value in a select statement with group by

Tags: sql-server, select, group-by

I have a table, and it's like this

> ID Num 
>   1 | 15 
>   2 | 16 
>   3 | 17 
>   1 | 18 
>   3 | 19

I was able to group them by its ID, but the problem is I want the Num of the ID to be it's highest Num

Like this:

> ID Num 
>   1 | 18 
>   2 | 16 
>   3 | 19

Answer (score 4):

```
select ID,Max(Num) from Your_Table group by ID
```

Read [Aggregate Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx) here.

Answer (score 2):

Use **Max()** Function

```
select id,max(Num) as Num from table group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the keyword `max` for getting the highest, and `min` for the lowest one.

For getting highest value:

```
select id,max(Num) as Num from tablename group by id
```

For getting lowest value:

```
select id,min(Num) as Num from tablename group by id
```